# What kind of test should I run for a newly built lab scale reactor assembly?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemical-engineering

I am a new graduate student working in thermochemical energy storage research. I have built a lab-scale model reactor for running hydration reactions. My advisor has asked me to run test of the reactor (without samples) to check whether things work. Let me describe the reactor.  The reactor is vertical and cylindrical-shaped. The lower part has an inlet for moist air flow. Then there is a diffuser which will disperse the airflow. After that, there is a humidity sensor which will provide relative humidity reading of the inlet flow. A vertical clearing has been kept after that for developing laminar flow. Then there is a sample bed (made with stainless steel coarse and fine mesh) over which the salt sample will be kept. Two thermocouples will be placed axially inside the sample to measure the temperature change of the sample. Finally, there will be another humidity sensor to know the relative humidity of outlet air. There is an outlet through which moist air will be exhausted. What kind of test should I run for testing? Can anyone describe in detail. This could be a dumb question but I am really struggling with my research understanding.

Comment: I felt a some relief after I read "hydration reactions".

Comment: why `Let me describe the reactor.`? ... why not `here is a diagram of the reactor`?

Comment: Test every control and sensor against every statement you made here. For example: "The lower part has an inlet for moist air flow" = test lower part inlet for moist air flow (is it moist? Does it flow? Under what conditions?)

Comment: general procedure:  list the functions and attributes of your apparatus. select which ones could possibly have doubts. then design a test for each one